# In GWT, how can I create the drawing for poll results? Are there any widgets/libraries for this or do I?

Tags: java, gwt, draw

Are there any libraries for drawing poll results or do I have to use the canvas to do this? Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do charts, you should check out the [Google Visualization API for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted).

Answer (score 1):

For a simple bar graph, I achieved some very satisfactory results by placing `SimplePanel`s in an `AbsolutePanel`.  You can set arbitrary positions and dimensions, add a stylename to access them through CSS and style them to the max.  Works in every browser down to IE 6, at least. You'd have to do the positioning math yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [glfot](http://code.google.com/p/gflot/).  It is more than capable of doing bar charts, and doesn't rely on connecting to google every time you want to calculate results.